# In Xcode - TableView Row Height <VS> TableViewCell Row Height

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

So I just noticed that, setting the TableView property of a UITableViewController's row height has more precedence over that table view's cells row height set in the storyboard.

When I change:

```
 self(*referring to view controller).tableView.rowHeight = 65 // Set row height as constant
```

And run, the row height changes based on this number.

However when I change the table view's individual cell row height property in interface builder (in the size inspector), I see the changed height on the storyboard, but again, when the app runs, it's as if this property does NOTHING. the row height seems to be based solely on the above code in the view controller.

In simplest terms, why is this / what's going on / what's the point of even setting the cell's row height if nothing is going to be affected?

Thanks

Comment: "what's the point of even setting the cell's row height" There is no point. The cell is part of a table view. You should use table view properties and the table view data source / delegate methods. Let the table view manage its cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableViewController` can have either static or dynamic content. For static content you add the cells in Interface Builder and it displays exactly that, for dynamic content you have to provide the number of sections/rows, the cells and other layout information.

If you change the height in Interface Builder, this will only be applied at runtime if your content is static.

If you're supplying the cells dynamically the table will use it's `tableView` property **unless** the delegate implements the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. The value you set in Interface Builder will be ignored in this case.